# The field of algebraic numbers in $\mathbb Q (a_1,\ldots, a_l)$ is finite over $\mathbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

In the book ['Algebra IV: Infinite Groups, Linear Groups'](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=O9cATtl-fowC&lpg=PA84&pg=PA84#v=onepage&q&f=false) by Kostrikin and Shafarevich, there is a sketch of a proof (on page 84) of a theorem by Schur. I'm struggling to understand the line:

> Since the field $\mathbb Q (a_1,\ldots, a_l)$ is finitely generated, the field $K$ of algebraic numbers in it is finite over $\mathbb Q$.

Why is this so? I can't find a proof for it anywhere. My best guess is that $K$ is a finitely generated algebra over $\mathbb Q$, and hence by the weak Nullstellensatz is of finite degree, but I can't see why $K$ would be finitely generated.

Comment: Doesn't it has to do more with the fact that an extension is finite iff is algebraic? I mean, if $a_1,...,a_l$ were already in $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Ana, it is not true in general that an algebraic extension is finite.

Comment: @GerryMyerson well maybe I'm interpretting wrongly this theorem that I have in my notes: $E/F$ is finite iff $E/F$ is algebraic and there exists $\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n\in E$ such that $E=F(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_n)$

Comment: But there are infinite algebraic extensions.

Comment: @AnaGalois: The second part "and the exists..." is essential, you can't skip it.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there ought to be an easy answer to this, but here's a hard work version.

Split the extension ${\mathbb Q}(a_1,\dots,a_n):{\mathbb Q}$ in a purely transcendental extension ${\mathbb Q}(t_1,\dots,t_k):{\mathbb Q}$ and an algebraic extension ${\mathbb Q}(a_1,\dots,a_n) :{\mathbb Q}(t_1,\dots,t_k)$. This last one, being algebraic and finitely generated, has finite degree, say $m$.

[image]

Now consider a single element of $K$. Its minimum polynomial over ${\mathbb Q}$ is also its minimum polynomial over ${\mathbb Q}(t_1,\dots,t_k)$, so has degree at most $m$. Since every finitely generated subfield of $K$ can be generated by a single element, every such finitely generated subfield has dimension at most $m$ over ${\mathbb Q}$. So every finite dimensional subspace of $K$ over $Q$, being contained in the subfield generated by a basis, has dimension at most $m$ over $Q$. Therefore $K$ itself has dimension at most $m$ over $Q$.

Comment: How does it follow that $K$ has dimension at most $m$? (I see how it does, but I don't think this is sufficiently trivial so as to be entirely omitted...)

Comment: @tomasz My last edit actually removed the argument :-( I've restored it.

Comment: I still don't think it's complete. Any vector space is the union of its $1$-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: @tomasz in this case, *all* finite dimensional subspaces have dimension at most m

Comment: But let me add a single sentence clarifying a small point anyway.

Comment: Yeah, that's right. :) But I wonder if the theorem would remain true if you replaced ${\bf Q}$ with an imperfect field of positive characteristic. I was thinking $F_p(X_n)_{n\in {\bf N}}$ would provide a counterexample, but I'm not so sure now.

Comment: @tomasz That's a nice question. Every element of the extension $F_p(X_1^p,X_2^p):F_p(X_1,X_2)$ has degree $p$ (or $1$), but the extension itself has degree $p^2$. This generalizes to $F_p(\{X_i^p\}_{i \in N}):F_p(\{X_i\}_{i \in N})$. Every element has degree $p$ (or $1$), but the extension itself has infinite degree. So at least my approach doesn't work if you replace ${\mathbb Q}$ by an imperfect field.

Comment: Really? I thoght so at first, but does $X_1+X_2$ have degree $p$ over  $F_p(X_1^p,X_2^p)$? I'm not sure. But my field theory is a little rusty, admittedly... I will post another question about this.

Comment: Here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/749479/30222

Comment: @tomasz Yes, the point is that if you raise any element of $F_p[X_1,X_2]$ to the power $p$, you wind up in in $F_p[X_1^p,X_2^p]$ because - in char $p$ - $(a + b)^p = a^p + b^p$. This means you never need terms of degree larger than $p$ in a minimum polynomial.