# Is the algebraic subextension of a finitely generated field extension finitely generated?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This question is motivated by [this other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/748164/30222) (and its answer).

Suppose we have a field $F$, possibly imperfect. Consider the finitely generated field extension $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$. Is it always true that $K=F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)\cap F^{\textrm{alg}}$ is finitely generated?

The proof from [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/748164/30222) generalises to case when $F$ is perfect (or more generally when $F(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is separable over $F$, I guess), thanks to the primitive element theorem.

But what about the general case? What if the initial extension is inseparable?

Comment: Is everything algebraic? If not, I think you can use counter-examples to the analog of Luroth theorem for greater transcendence degree.

Comment: @user40276: Of course it isn't. If everything was algebraic, the question would be completely trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given an arbitrary field extension $F\subset G$, if $G$ is finitely generated (as a field) over $F$, then any intermediate field extension $F\subset K\subset G$ is also finitely generated over $F$.
Applying this to your situation (with $G=F(a_1,\cdots,a_n))$ you see immediately that your $K$ is both algebraic and finitely generated over $F$ so that actually it is even a finite-dimensional vector space over $F$.

The powerful theorem mentioned in the first sentence is unfortunately not as well-known as it should.
As often the best reference is Bourbaki: [Algebra](http://books.google.fr/books/about/Algebra_II.html?id=bDLecF34d8UC&redir_esc=y), Chapter 5, §15, Corollary 3, page 118.

Comment: Interesting. Though it should be noted that in the version you linked, the corollary is on the page 224 (of the entire book, not just the chapter) *and* it is in paragraph 14, not 15. Also, the proof is remarkably simple. :)

Comment: Dear @tomasz, yes, the result  is in §14: corrected. As to your other comment: Bourbaki has written a splendid chapter on field theory and His aim was not to arrive quickly or slowly at the result under discussion, but to develop the theory in a harmonious and natural way. Your last sentence confirms that He has succeeded.

Answer (score 2):

Let $T$ be a transcendence basis of $F(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)/F$. Then $F(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)/F(T)$ is a finite extension and $F(T)$ and $K$ are linearly disjoint over $F$. Hence the cardinality of any $F$-linearly independent set of elements of $K$ is bounded from above by the degree of $F(a_1,\ldots ,a_n)/F(T)$.

If an algebraic extension $K/F$ of fields is not finite, then within $F$ there exists an infinite tower of proper finite extensions $K\subset K_1\subset K_2\subset \ldots $. Since $K_i$ is a $K$-sub vectorspace of $K_{i+1}$ a basis of $K_i$ can be extended to a basis of $K_{i+1}$. Thus the above infinite tower yields an infinite $K$-linearly independent set within $F$. By linear disjointness this set remains linearly independent over $F(T)$ - a contradiction.

Comment: But how does the second sentence follow, exactly? That's pretty much exactly the point of this question...